# Hide other buttons on mouseover

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have a dynamic array of buttons and I want to hide others when one is hovered. There is a [REPL here](https://svelte.dev/repl/2a98b5e7faeb4fedb621d4f5450c011a?version=3.22.3) with my attempt.

It went well until I have to update a child prop from the parent. I get this error :

```
Props cannot be set directly on the component instance unless compiling with 'accessors: true' or '<svelte:options accessors/>'
```

So I put the option line in my Btn.svelte but I still get an error. Am I missing something ? Or maybe there is an easier way ??

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was another error, you didn't clear the `isOpaque` field when the button is actually hovered. Then, I suggest an optimization, the `{#each}` repeater emits the current index, so we don't need an extra variable for this. Here's my correction/suggestion using the `$set` method to update the component property:

```
<script>
    import Btn from "./Btn.svelte";
    let current;
    const data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    let btns = [];

    function overed (e) {
        console.log("overed :" + e.detail.data);
        btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
            btn.$set({isOpaque: e.detail.data !== data[i]})
        })
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>

{#each data as item, index}
<Btn on:overed={overed} data={item} bind:this={btns[index]}>{item}</Btn>
{/each}
```

And here is a simplified version that does not require updating the child components property from the parent:

https://svelte.dev/repl/f049fb762bfb481ca3c8998879a3cdb3?version=3.22.3

Comment: Thank you for this. Your code is more clear but it does not seem to change opacity on rollover though. Do you know why ?

Comment: Hmm, the REPL that I provided does it - at least that's how I understood your idea ^^ The buttons not under the mouse are shown dimmed. What did you expect?

Comment: Every button is opacity:1, when I hover one it changes to orange and the other ones fade at opacity:0.5. When I rollout every buttons go back to opacity:1.

Comment: That was easy :) updated the REPL, just refresh. The change is on APP.svelte, line 12

Answer (score 1):

change:
`btns[i].isOpaque = true;`
to:
`btns[i].$set({isOpaque:true});`.

[docs reference](https://svelte.dev/docs#$set)

Comment: Thank you @2pha. I don't see any mention of this $get in documentation... How do we know that it exists ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the diagnostic messages closely. It says this...

> Props cannot be set directly on the component instance unless compiling with `accessors: true` or `<svelte:options accessors/>`

...but your component has...

```
<svelte options accessors={true}/>
```

...which isn't the same thing at all!